# How can it be done in React JS Material UI that if I type in the last newline in the datagrid view, it shows another newline below it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

[Example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbsBe.png)

How can it be done in React JS Material UI that if I type in the last newline in the datagrid view, it shows another newline below it?

How can I do it in gridview in Material UI as shown in the above photo.